# Parsing "true" and "false" using Boost.Spirit.Lex and Boost.Spirit.Qi

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

As the first stage of a larger grammar using Boost.Spirit I'm trying to parse "true" and "false" to produce the corresponding bool values, `true` and `false`.

I'm using Spirit.Lex to tokenize the input and have a working implementation for integer and floating point literals (including those expressed in a relaxed scientific notation), exposing `int` and `float` attributes.

### Token definitions

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>

namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;

typedef boost::mpl::vector<int, float, bool> token_value_type;

template <typename Lexer>
struct basic_literal_tokens : lex::lexer<Lexer> {
    basic_literal_tokens() { 
        this->self.add_pattern("INT", "[-+]?[0-9]+");
        int_literal = "{INT}";
        // To be lexed as a float a numeric literal must have a decimal point
        // or include an exponent, otherwise it will be considered an integer.
        float_literal = "{INT}(((\\.[0-9]+)([eE]{INT})?)|([eE]{INT}))";

        literal_true = "true";
        literal_false = "false";
        this->self = literal_true | literal_false | float_literal | int_literal;
    }

    lex::token_def<int> int_literal;
    lex::token_def<float> float_literal;
    lex::token_def<bool> literal_true, literal_false;
};
```

### Testing parsing of float literals

My real implementation uses Boost.Test, but this is a self-contained example.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>

bool parse_and_check_float(std::string const & input, float expected) {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator base_iterator_type;
    typedef lex::lexertl::token<base_iterator_type,
                token_value_type
            > token_type;
    typedef lex::lexertl::lexer<token_type> lexer_type;

    basic_literal_tokens<lexer_type> basic_literal_lexer;
    base_iterator_type input_iter(input.begin());

    float actual;

    bool result = lex::tokenize_and_parse(input_iter, input.end(),
                                          basic_literal_lexer,
                                          basic_literal_lexer.float_literal,
                                          actual);
    return result && std::abs(expected - actual) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (parse_and_check_float("+31.4e-1", 3.14)) {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

### Parsing "true" and "false"

My problem is when trying to parse "true" and "false". This is the test code I'm using (after removing the Boost.Test parts):

```
bool parse_and_check_bool(std::string const & input, bool expected) {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator base_iterator_type;
    typedef lex::lexertl::token<base_iterator_type,
                token_value_type
            > token_type;
    typedef lex::lexertl::lexer<token_type> lexer_type;

    basic_literal_tokens<lexer_type> basic_literal_lexer;
    base_iterator_type input_iter(input.begin());

    bool actual;
    lex::token_def<bool> parser = expected ? basic_literal_lexer.literal_true
                                           : basic_literal_lexer.literal_false;
    bool result = lex::tokenize_and_parse(input_iter, input.end(),
                                          basic_literal_lexer, parser,
                                          actual);
    return result && actual == expected;
}
```

but compilation fails with:

```
boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp: In function ‘void boost::spirit::traits::assign_to(const Iterator&, const Iterator&, Attribute&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Attribute = bool]’:
boost/spirit/home/lex/lexer/lexertl/token.hpp:434:   instantiated from ‘static void boost::spirit::traits::assign_to_attribute_from_value<Attribute, boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::token<Iterator, AttributeTypes, HasState>, void>::call(const boost::spirit::lex::lexertl::token<Iterator, AttributeTypes, HasState>&, Attribute&) [with Attribute = bool, Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, AttributeTypes = boost::mpl::vector<int, float, bool, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, HasState = mpl_::bool_<true>]’

... backtrace of instantiation points ....

boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:79: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::spirit::traits::assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<bool, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, void>::call(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, bool&)’
boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/construct.hpp:64: note: candidates are: static void boost::spirit::traits::assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<bool, Iterator, void>::call(const Iterator&, const Iterator&, char&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]
```

My interpretation of this is that Spirit.Qi doesn't know how to convert a string to a bool - surely that's not the case? Has anyone else done this before? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually looks like it is a bug in Spirit 2.4.1 which has already been fixed in subversion. The log message is `"Spirit: Fixing cut&paste error, adding missing specializations for assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<>."` (r66624 checked in by hkaiser on 2010-11-18).

Answer (score 2):

You want something like

```
qi::rule<Iterator, bool> true_false_parser;
a = qi::lexeme[ qi::no_case[ qi::eps > ( qi::lit("true")[ _val=true] | qi::lit("false")[ _val=false] ) ] ];
```

This will throw iff the token is not "true" or "false"

To default false do

```
qi::rule<Iterator, bool> true_false_parser;
a = qi::lexeme[ qi::no_case[ ( qi::lit("true")[ _val=true] ) | (*qi::char_)[_val=false] ] ];
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't your solution preclude the use of Spirit.Lex? You're matching literal strings but the parser would be iterating over tokens.

Comment: I believe the use of lexeme fixes that. There is also, IIRC, a qi::raw that allows access to the underlying characters. I have never had much luck with Lex and prefer to just use Qi to do my lexing.

Comment: Fair enough, that looks like a good way to do it purely in Qi (which is the only reason I'm not accepting your answer, by the way). I'd upvote you but I'm new here and don't have the rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided compiles fine for me using Spirit V2.4.1 (as released with oost V1.45). It seems you're suffering from a bug, which already has been fixed in the newest version.

Comment: Hi Hartmut, how are you obtaining your version of Spirit 2.4.1? I've checked both the [Boost 1.45.0 tarball from Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.45.0/) (specifically, the tar.bz2 version) and the [release/Boost_1_45_0 svn tag](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/tags/release/Boost_1_45_0) and they both have the bug in boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/construct.hpp . I can only see the fix in [trunk](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk) and [branches/release](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/branches/release/), which according to version.hpp will be Boost 1.46